# Find and delete duplicate friend connections in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need a script to find Member who has a friend connection more than once so it doesn't show their friendship more than once on the website.

The MemberConnection table is as follows:

```
+----------------------+------------+----------------+
|  MemberConnectionID  |  MemberID  |  ConnMemberID  |
+----------------------+------------+----------------+
|  25                  |  33        | 43             |
|  26                  |  43        | 33             |
|  27                  |  13        | 143            |
|  28                  |  143       | 13             |
|  29                  |  33        | 43             |
+----------------------+------------+----------------+
```

As you can see rows 25 and 29 are identical and I need to find these duplicates so they can be deleted.

How can I write a script for this?

Any help that anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

neojakey

Comment: You want to delete both it?

Comment: Do you want to delete one row or two rows? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: How about you create a `UNIQUE` constraint on `MemberID, ConnMemberID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this if you want to leave one connection:

Use this to select connections:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT
      MemberConnectionID, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID, ConnMemberID ORDER BY MemberConnectionID) RN
   FROM MemberConnection 
)
SELECT 
      MemberConnectionID
FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

or use this to delete from table:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID, ConnMemberID ORDER BY MemberConnectionID) RN
   FROM MemberConnection 
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT MemberID,ConnMemberID  ,count( MemberID,ConnMemberID ) as c FROM MemberConnection group by MemberID,ConnMemberID ) x 
WHERE x.c >1
```

This will show you all repeated rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using this as a test:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE
    (
      MemberConnectionID INT ,
      MemberID INT ,
      ConMemberID INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @Table
        SELECT  1 ,
                2 ,
                3
INSERT  INTO @Table
        SELECT  2 ,
                3 ,
                4
INSERT  INTO @Table
        SELECT  3 ,
                2 ,
                3
```

**Select occurence of member connections**

```
SELECT    COUNT(MemberConnectionID) AS Occurence ,
          MemberID ,
          ConMemberID
FROM      @Table
GROUP BY  MemberID ,
          ConMemberID
```

**Delete Statement**

```
DELETE  FROM @Table
FROM    @Table t
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT MemberID ,
                            ConMemberID
                     FROM   ( SELECT    COUNT(MemberConnectionID) AS Occurence ,
                                        MemberID ,
                                        ConMemberID
                              FROM      @Table
                              GROUP BY  MemberID ,
                                        ConMemberID
                            ) t2
                     WHERE  t2.Occurence > 1
                   ) t3 ON t3.MemberID = T.MemberID
                           AND t3.ConMemberID = t.ConMemberID
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this little query (changed to meet your table).

```
Delete MemberConnection
from MemberConnection
join
(select max(MemberConnectionId)as CountIt, MemberId, ConnMemberId
    from #MemberConnection
    group by MemberId, ConnMemberId
    having count(1) > 1
) as derived
on MemberConnection.MemberId = derived.MemberId
and MemberConnection.ConnMemberId = derived.ConnMemberId
and CountIt > MemberConnectionId
```